# Why can't I link to one template from another?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

I am using Play 2.6 and for the first time am having issue inserting another template into another one.

Here's my structure:
[image]

And here's the template projectView I'm currently working on:

```
@import views.html.afterLogin.projectWorkspace._
@import views.html.afterLogin.dashboard

@(projectName: String, userName: String)


@main(s"Track Wild: $projectName") {

    @loggedInNavbar("projects", userName)

    @dasboard("name")

    @projectToolbar

    @success

    <h1>Stuff</h1>


}
```

IntelliJ is telling me it cannot resolve:

`@dasboard("name")`

`@projectToolbar`

and the `html` in `@import views.html.afterLogin.dashboard`

It's also saying the import statements are both unused. However, I can link just fine to some of the other templates in other packages higher up in the chain. I can't figure out why it's allowing some and not others...

Comment: You've shown the contents of `projectView.scala.html` but it sounds like the problem is actually in `dashboard.scala.html`. What's the output of `sbt clean compile`?

Comment: It's `[error] /Users/route/to/project/app/controllers/LoginRegController.scala:46: Cannot write an instance of play.api.mvc.Call to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[play.api.mvc.Call]
[error]             Ok(routes.DashboardController.index)
`

Comment: That was a separate error though. Fixed it, and `sbt clean compile` gives me success. But no fix to the issue.

Comment: not sure in what order this "fixed" the posted issue, but I ran
`sbt clean compile` and then closed the project in IntelliJ and reopened, and it then solved everything. However, replicated this again, and it did not fix the problem. Any new template created cannot be found nor referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but it was something with IntelliJ:

I clicked File -> Invalid Caches/Restart

Before I did that, I had also gone into my project structure and:

target-> scala-2.12. -> twirl

ctrl + click: Mark Directory as: unexcluded

I don't know if this did anything though. Try invalidating the cache and let IntelliJ do a full restart (let it finish indexing everything) first. If that doesn't do it, then try unexcluding the twirl directory, THEN invalidating the caches and restarting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the line with @dasboard("name") might contain a typo in "dashboard", see if that helps in solving the issue any further.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Rhiq .  One line suggestions on troubleshooting steps are usually best received as a comment to the question, rather than as an answer.  Answers should be more complete and offer guidance on why that is the solution.

Comment: Hello @Degan .I tried to use the comment section but apparently it requires 50 reputation. Thank you for pointing this out though!

Comment: Good eye, but unfortunately that was a typo just made in recreating the issue for the question here. All things are spelled correctly in the actual environment. Thanks though!